# Dynamic Frame Option based on Selection Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get an option based on the curser selection of the first frame. Let's say Frame1 has two options ['abc','def'] corresponding to those two options selection in "Frame2" we should get their values. So, if 'abc' is selected using a curser selection in Frame1 than corresponding 'g', 'h','i' should get populated in Frame2 Similarly to the case with 'def'.

I have written below the code. however, I am not getting the desired output. could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

[Tkinter output which shows frame two doesn't have any value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rADrk.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
import os

# Creating GUI Framework
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.config(bg='light blue')

# Setting up two frames within GUI.
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TFrame',background='blue')

s.configure('Frame0.TFrame',background='light blue')
frame0 = ttk.Frame(root,style='Frame0.TFrame')
frame0.place(anchor='w',relx=.05,rely=.35)

s.configure('Frame1.TFrame',background='light blue')
frame1 = ttk.Frame(root,style='Frame1.TFrame')
frame1.place(anchor='e',relx=.6,rely=.35)

# First Frame Data and List Box.
label1 = ['abc','def']
rf = StringVar()
rfl = list((set(label1)))
rf.set(rfl)

lstbox0 = Listbox(frame0,listvariable=rf,selectmode=MULTIPLE,width=20,height=10,fg='blue',bg='light blue')
lstbox0.grid(column=5,row=5,columnspan=3)

# Second frame data need to pop up dynamically when first frame got selected.
rflist = list()
a1 = ['g','h','i']
a2 = ['j','k','l']
def rf_selection():
    rf_selected = lstbox0.curselection()
    for i in rf_selected:
        rflist = list()
        entry_rf = lstbox0.get(i)
        if entry_rf == 'abc':
            rflist.append(a1)
        elif entry_rf == 'def':
            rflist.append(a2)
        else:
            rflist.append("")
    return rflist

tests = StringVar()
tests.set(rflist)

lstbox1 = Listbox(frame1,listvariable=tests,selectmode=MULTIPLE,width=20,height=10,fg='blue',bg='light blue')
lstbox1.grid(column=10,row=5,columnspan=3)

# This button is only to show option in second list box based on what option is selected in first frame.
btn_open = ttk.Button(frame0,text="Show RF",command=rf_selection)
btn_open.grid(row=17,column=6)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you select value and append to `rflist` but you have to put in `tests` which is assigned to `Listbox`

Answer (score 0):

You define `lstbox1` with `listvariable=tests` so in `rf_selection()` you have to add values to `tests`

```
tests.set(rflist)
```

like

```
def rf_selection():

    rf_selected = lstbox0.curselection()

    rflist = list()   # before `for`-loop

    for i in rf_selected:

        entry_rf = lstbox0.get(i)

        if entry_rf == 'abc':
            rflist.append(a1)
        elif entry_rf == 'def':
            rflist.append(a2)
        else:
            rflist.append("")

    tests.set(rflist)

    #return rflist  # useless
```

---

**BTW:**

You could keep values as dictionary

```
options = {
    'abc': ['g','h','i'],
    'def': ['j','k','l'],
}
```

and set values in first list using `options.keys()`

```
values = list(options.keys()) 
rf.set( values )
```

and in second list (in `rf_selection()`)

```
if entry_rf in options:
   value = options[entry_rf]
   rf_list.append(value)

# ... at the end ...

test.set( rf_list )
```

And if you want to put  `['g','h','i']` as 3 options then you can use `extend()` (or `+=`) instead of `append()`

---

Minimal working code with other changes.

I removed all not important elements.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def rf_selection():
    
    selected = lstbox0.curselection()

    new_list = []
    
    for number in selected:
        entry = lstbox0.get(number)
        
        if entry in options:
            values = options[entry]
            new_list.append(values)
            #new_list.extend(values)  # every value as separated line
            #new_list += values       # every value as separated line

    # set values in variable assigned by `listvariable=list_2`
    list_2.set(new_list)
     
# --- main ---

options = {
    'abc': ['1','2','3'],
    'def': ['4','5','6'],
    'ghi': ['7','8','9'],
    'jkl': ['10','11', '12'],
}

# --- 

root = tk.Tk()

frame0 = tk.Frame(root)
frame0.grid(column=0, row=0)

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='n')

list_1 = tk.StringVar(root)
list_1.set( list(options.keys()) )

lstbox0 = tk.Listbox(frame0, listvariable=list_1, selectmode='multiple', bg='light blue')
lstbox0.grid(column=0, row=0)

list_2 = tk.StringVar(root)

lstbox1 = tk.Listbox(frame1, listvariable=list_2, selectmode='multiple', bg='light blue')
lstbox1.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn_open = tk.Button(frame0, text="Show RF", command=rf_selection)
btn_open.grid(column=0, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Using `append()`

[image]

Using `extend()` or `+=`

[image]

Comment: Thanks furas for your help. It worked for me.